# Simulating a Java EE based website

Tags: java, web, simulation, application-server

I am looking for a tool that can help **simulate a Java EE based website**, to help test another application server monitoring and performance tool.

The test tool should be a website of some sort that can manually or automatically simulate user usage of this website, including error invocation (automatic browsing and clicking, database access, database error invocation, code exception, etc.)

Example of a similar but **very basic** manual tool is the **BEA MedRec**, that simulates a Medical Records website for user manual testing and comes as part of the BEA WebLogic Application Server.

Comment: I don't understand what you're looking for. A sample JEE app that can be deployed? Or a tool to simulate many users interacting with an existing JEE app? Or both?

Comment: Sorry if my question was not so clear. I would need a sample J2EE App that can be deployed.  If possible it will be best that this app can simulate a user (or users) interacting with it.

Comment: Maybe a more specific request could be a Real World Test application for JBoss. Do you know of one?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) but is does not simulate your application server.  It only simulates a browser using you application.

You can also try [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) if you want to perform some stress testing.

Comment: I need a complete test website. You are right Selenium could be part of the automation of the test website if it does not come built in.